# how to set tmp path and log pat

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I am trying to set tem directory path and logs dir path in my joomla site .
my site folder path is this "`/httpdocs/example.com/online`" and my site url this

```
http://dev.maindomain.com/example/online/.
```

please let me know .I do not what will be my root path of temp file .Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a PHP file called `whereami.php` with the following contents and upload to the root folder of your website:

```
<?php
  print 'Current dir is ' . dirname(__FILE__);
?>
```

Run the file by browsing to `yoursitename.com/whereami.php` and this will show you the path to the root folder of your website.

By default, the logs and tmp folders are sub folders of the root path.

Remember to delete the `whereami.php` folder when you are finished.

Answer (score 3):

In cPanel hosting this usually looks like:

```
/home/username/public_html/tmp
/home/username/public_html/logs
```

In your system, it should be similar, but for the exact path better consult your hosting provider.

Note that it's very likely that this information is available and visible somewhere within your hosting account / hosting control panel, so you may find it by looking around.